# Define multiple variable of same datatype in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am creating a Azure Logic App. I need to Define multiple variable of same datatype. What is the quickest / good way to define it. I tried   code view  to add more variables but seems its not supported yet:

[image]
[image]

Comment: So, what else have you tried?  The answer is literally in that same screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the purpose of all the variables except for the obvious to store the data? My question is. Is it possible to parse the data into dynamic content by a Parse JSON action which a schema to store them as dynamic content with type string?

Otherwise, you will have to add multiple Initialize Variable actions after each other.

You could also store the data in a Variable array and work with it from there. Store it in an array and if you prefer [Javascript inline Code](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/inline-code-for-azure-logic-apps-is-in-public-preview/)

[image: Store Array with append Array Variable action]

Comment: some mathematical calculations needs to be done and require many variables to be defined.

Comment: how do we access the workflow variables, `Countries` in this example, in the inline code?

Comment: variables('Countries').name